# How to send diffrent keystrokes to multiple processes at the same time(relatively) in C++?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

How to send diffrent keystrokes to multiple processes at the same time(relatively) in C++?

Thus far I have seen SendInput and SendMessage, but I am interested in how would I go about sending different keystrokes to different processes at pretty much the same time.

Thank you all for your time and effort in advance.

OS: Windows 10 64bit

Comment: Just send them with `SendInput`? What's wrong with that?

Comment: The thing is I wish to send let us say 10 diffrent keystrokes to let us say 10 diffent processes at the same time.

Comment: Not sure if you could achieve this with SendInput. If you can. Could you please provide a link to an example or an example of such usage.

Comment: `SendInput` simulates keypresses, so the keystrokes are only received by the current foreground window. You could `SendMessage` (or `PostMessage`) with WM_KEYDOWN, WM_KEYUP, but it might behave differently. If the receiving process uses accelerators or calls `GetKeyState`, this might not work.

Comment: There in lies the problem, if I need 10 diffrent keystrokes at the same time to 10 different processes, they wont all be in the foreground, so I need to be able to send them even if they are in the background.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Why do you feel that faking input is the solution to your problem?

Comment: @PasserBy: *"What's wrong with that?"* - How do you propose to send input to multiple processes using `SendInput`, or even just to a single specific process? Does that sufficiently answer your question?

Comment: Well I have multiple programs that accept keyboard input, that I wish to control via my program. Which should be able  to send keystrokes and in such a way control actions within those programs.

Comment: You will have to send it to each process individually, there is no way around that.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should acquire handles to all windows you're going to send keystrokes to.

After it, you can send messages representing keystrokes to these windows via [`PostMessage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644944(v=vs.85).aspx) function. This function returns without waiting for the thread to process the message, so you can post a lot of keystrokes at relatively the same time. This method has drawbacks:

1. Not all applications use only message queue to interact with keyboard
2. You should be consistent about messages you post (don't forget to release keys after pressing them, etc)

See [System-Defined Messages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644927(v=vs.85).aspx#system_defined) at MSDN for a list of messages to send and how to make a message from keystroke.